# Quartz.Net Load Balancing via Web Service

Tags: asp.net, cluster-computing, quartz.net

I'm new to Quartz.NET, so please bear with me here.

I'm using Quartz as part of a website that is running on a cluster of servers.  In order to facilitate load balancing of the jobs, they are making calls to a web service (running on the same website) via a load balancer to ensure that they are executed on the web server with the least load.  Some of these jobs may take several hours to complete.  The problem with this is that the Quartz job and the web service may be running on different machines.  If the machine running the Quartz job crashes while waiting for the web service to complete on another machine then Quartz will not know if the task completed without issue.  I could call the web service asynchronously, but then Quartz will simply think that the job completed successfully immediately regardless of what happens in the web service.  This won't allow me to make sure that the same job doesn't run concurrently since Quartz will think that it completed.  It also doesn't allow for retrying on failure or allow me to see which jobs are currently running.

Is there a feature in Quartz that I'm overlooking?  Has anyone else had to handle a similar situation?  Is there a better way to load balance Quartz jobs?

For now, I'm thinking that I'll need to modify the Quartz JobRunShell class to not set the complete status of the job and trigger (not sure if this is the right place?).  Then allow my web service to set the statuses when it has completed.  I'll also need to add code to handle cases where the web service crashes and the job is never completed.  To do this, I'm planning on my web service creating a thread to periodically tell Quartz that the job is still running (via a new timestamp field that I'll add to the database).  I'll have to periodically check the running jobs to see if they are still running (via the new field) and if they haven't been updated in a while (say 5 times the update period) then I'll assume that the job has failed and make the job as failed and retry (where applicable).

Any help / comments would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using Quartz.Net version 2.3

Comment: Which jobstore are you using? How many apps make calls to the web service?

Comment: @CircularReference Using the JobStoreTX.  The web service is being created specifically for use by Quartz, so just the one application.

Comment: @Graham Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz [clustering](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/advanced-enterprise-features.html) feature performs load-balancing by itself. If you use that, you can entirely avoid having your job calling the webservice. Instead you will configure your job to directly run the code you need, and the quartz load-balancing will select which machine will run the job depending on the load. Although [clustering](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/advanced-enterprise-features.html) supports exists for quartz.net, it is only at the java version of quartz documentation where you can find a nice explanation on how that  works at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

For clustering to work you should set `quartz.jobStore.clustered=true` property, and [configure an ADO.NET JobStore](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html)

Comment: In the article it says that "Load-balancing occurs automatically, with each node of the cluster firing jobs as quickly as it can."  That doesn't really sound like proper load balancing to me as it is simply hoping that the lowest load instance will pick up the task, which isn't necessarily the case.  Wouldn't it be necessary for Quartz to check on server resource utilization to do this?  I assume that is how a web load balancer works.

Comment: I don't know how quartz works underneath, but I think I'll agree with you. In my case the simplicity of configuring quartz clustering without the need to implement functionality myself and have worries like yours and additional complexity that would hinter maintainability made me easily select it. If you think that your case cannot be properly addressed by quartz clustering, by all means do not use it. I would give it a try though, after all it is a Quartz feature built for this purpose.

Comment: I looked a little into Network Load Balancing and it turns out that it just even distributes the number of requests, without concern for the actual server load.  That's pretty much what Quartz is doing already.  I'll have to look into the source code for Quartz a bit more and do some load testing to see how well it works.  Thanks @Marios.